# OpenType not showing the package org.w3c.dom from the dependencies that have been added

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, java-17

I'm upgrading from java 11 to 17, and there is one issue which says **The package org.w3c.dom is accessible from more than one module: , java.xml** . While searching on stackoverflow, i got one solution to find the transitive dependency and remove it from pom by exclusion tag, but open type is not showing any such package.

Please refer this image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGGAG.png) that depicts that Node class and only one package which is within jdk 17 and no other dependency is having the same package, but still this issue is there [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmRc7.png).I have checked my project and org.w3c.dom package is not present in 3rd party libs or added by any transitive dependencies in the project jars.

EDIT - 1 output of mvn dependency :tree

```
com.apc:designportal:war:22.1.2
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.19:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.19:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.19:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.19:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:5.3.19:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.19:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.19:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.3.19:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.3.19:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.3.19:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.3.19:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.3.19:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.3.19:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.7.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:5.7.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.7.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security.extensions:spring-security-saml2-core:jar:1.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.opensaml:opensaml:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.opensaml:openws:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.opensaml:xmltooling:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15:jar:1.46:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- ca.juliusdavies:not-yet-commons-ssl:jar:0.3.9:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:jar:1.5.6:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.owasp.esapi:esapi:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1:runtime
[INFO] |     \- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:runtime
[INFO] +- org.json:json:jar:20171018:compile
[INFO] +- displaytag:displaytag:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] +- asm:asm-attrs:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] +- asm:asm:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.6.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.4.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.4.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.24.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.9.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.1.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.dom4j:dom4j:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.7:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:jar:1.2.15:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:jar:5.4.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.10.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.tapestry:tapestry-core:jar:5.2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tapestry:tapestry-ioc:jar:5.2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tapestry:tapestry5-annotations:jar:5.2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tapestry:tapestry-func:jar:5.2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tapestry:tapestry-json:jar:5.2.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.0.1:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jsp-api:jar:2.0:provided
[INFO] |  \- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- jstl:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.2:compile
[INFO] +- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] +- javax.xml.ws:jaxws-api:jar:2.2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.soap:saaj-api:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish:javax.annotation:jar:3.1.1:runtime
[INFO] |  \- javax.jws:jsr181-api:jar:1.0-MR1:runtime
[INFO] +- javax.jws:javax.jws-api:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.17.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.17.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.10.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-bean-collections:jar:1.8.3:compile
[INFO] +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.8.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.3.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.googlecode.jsontoken:jsontoken:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.collections:google-collections:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.easymock:easymock:jar:4.0.2:test
[INFO] |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.0.1:test
[INFO] +- org.easymock:easymockclassextension:jar:3.2:test
[INFO] +- com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:jar:8.2.2.jre11:compile
[INFO] +- com.gutor.configurators.validator:gutor-design-validator:jar:0.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:jar:5.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7.js2:compile
[INFO] |  \- eclipse:jdtcore:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- ar.com.fdvs:DynamicJasper:jar:4.0.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:4.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.zaxxer:SparseBitSet:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.apc.oracle.pricing:oracle-ws:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.apc.oracle.pricing:http_client:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.apc.designtools:dp-configurator-integration:jar:0.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.apc.designtools:dp-quotingsystem-integration:jar:0.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.jdom:jdom:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- axis:axis:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.axis:axis-jaxrpc:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.axis:axis-saaj:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-discovery:commons-discovery:jar:0.2:runtime
[INFO] +- axis:axis-wsdl4j:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-adb:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.axis2:axis2-kernel:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.ws.commons.schema:XmlSchema:jar:1.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.neethi:neethi:jar:2.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-api:jar:1.2.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.ws.commons.axiom:axiom-impl:jar:1.2.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-transcoder:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-anim:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-awt-util:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.xmlgraphics:xmlgraphics-commons:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-bridge:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-dom:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-gvt:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svggen:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-util:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-constants:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-i18n:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-xml:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-codec:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-extension:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-css:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-ext:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-parser:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-svg-dom:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-gui-util:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-swing:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.xmlgraphics:batik-script:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] +- com.googlecode.charts4j:charts4j:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- net.glxn:qrgen:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.zxing:javase:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.google.zxing:core:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- c3p0:c3p0:jar:0.9.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- opensymphony:quartz-all:jar:1.6.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.moxy:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.core:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.asm:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.antlr:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.auth0:java-jwt:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:4.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.19:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.github.virtuald:curvesapi:jar:1.06:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:ooxml-schemas:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:4.1.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.github.luben:zstd-jni:jar:1.4.4-7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.lz4:lz4-java:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.7.3:compile
[INFO] \- org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.kafka:connect-json:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.kafka:connect-api:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO]    |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.10.2:compile
[INFO]    \- org.rocksdb:rocksdbjni:jar:5.18.4:compile
```

also, attaching the image after searching org.w3c.dom.* in openType.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nme0C.png)

Comment: In the _Open Type_ enter `org.w3c.dom.*` instead of `org.w3c.dom.Node` since there seems to be another `org.w3c.dom` package not containing `org.w3c.dom.Node`.

Comment: Can you run `mvn dependency:tree` and share the output?

Comment: @howlger I searched with org.w3c.dom.* and got many outputs, can you please help me in how to remove that exclusion?

Comment: @dan1st yes added in the edits.

Comment: The root cause seems to be quite outdated dependencies.

Comment: Hi @howlger , as you said I removed all the transitive dependencies that came with org.w3.dom.*and it worked. !! thanks a lot but can you please advice me like which dependencies should I upgrade to a newer version.

Comment: Removing the transitive dependencies just hides the problem. For security reasons, make sure that all your dependencies are up to date. IMHO this would be more important than upgrading from Java 11 to 17.